# Expanding Quadratic form

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, quadratic-forms

I am currently working on a problem and I am trying to convince myself that given a sequence of real number $\{s_n\}$, that truly the constants  $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are zero if the quadratic form  $$\sum_{i,j=0}^{n}s_{i+j}c_ic_j = 0.$$

I transformed the quadratic form into matrix form $c^TAc =0$ but still can not convince myself. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you mean $\sum_{ i, j  = 0}^n (s_i + s_j) c_i c_j = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

We have that matrix $A = [s_i + s_j]$ is a real symmetric matrix. Now, it doesn't have to be that $c^T A c = 0 \implies c = \mathbf 0.$ Consider the sequence $\{-1,0,1\}$ with the corresponding matrix 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

and the vector $c = [1\quad 0\quad -1]^T$. It holds that $c^TAc = 0.$